# Definition of chain of tree

Tags: graph-theory, definition, trees

I am trouble understanding the definition of chain of tree at [p15](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/Ch1.pdf).

Here is a rooted tree. The root is "a".
abc is clearly chain. 
However, I cannot understand whether bc is chain or not.

a
|
bーd
|
c

At first, I thought chain is only "abc","ab","a","abd".

But looking at the proof of Lemma1.5.5(ii), "bc" should be included. Which is correct?

Comment: $b$, $c$, $bc$ and $bd$ are chains.  Also $ac$ and $ad$ are chains.  A chain is a set of pairwise comparable elements. (I'm leaving out the braces.)   Intuitively, this means they all lie on the same path from the  root to a leaf.  (Look at the definition of $xPy$ on page $7$ to understand the definition of "tree order.")

Comment: I also had a problem with the definition of a chain as I was missing a definition of vertex comparability until I realized it refers to the binary relations $\le$ (and similar) defined on the same page. Therefore, in your example only $d$ and $c$ are incomparable because neither $d \in aTc$ nor $c \in aTd$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are giving an example of a chain as the down-set. So a chain is a subset of the graph with comparable elements(a linear ordering), The down-set of a vertex is an example of a chain. So, indeed **bc** is chain in the graph. They are completely comparable.